# UITableViewCells are out of order

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Okay, I am having another UITableView problem. For some reason the indexPath.row is all jumbled up. When I comment out the if statement that sets up the cell, everything works fine. The NSLogs tell me that they are loading in order, but all the cells are out of order.

It also seems as if they repeat; I only see 8 cells, and they repeat over and over.

Here's my code:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NSLog(@"row: %d",indexPath.row);

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Add subviews like this:
    // [[cell contentView] addSubview:objectName];
    // And I get the row number like this: indexPath.row when getting objects from the array

}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use your code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NSLog(@"row: %d",indexPath.row);

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        // Add subviews like this:
        // [[cell contentView] addSubview:objectName];


    }
     ### Move this here ###
// And I get the row number like this: indexPath.row when getting objects from the array
return cell;
}
```

" I only see 8 cells, and they repeat over and over." Correct.

What your missing is that that is how it is supposed to work. That's why only if the cell is nil are you alloc & init'ing a new cell. So you alloc and init and set the colors and add subviews in the if statement. Then after the `if(cell==nil)` you know you have a valid cell to populate with some data according to the `indexPath` variable passed in.

The problem is that now you are setting up the cell when it is nil and assigning all of the displayed data according to the `indexPath` passed in. The problem is cell is not nil the second time it's used so the data is never changed.

To address your speed comment further, I'll use an old fallback example.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UILabel *hugeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
        hugeLabel.tag = 300;
        [cell addSubview:hugeLabel];
    }
    [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:300] setText:[arrayOfStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

If you look at the sample above, you'll see that we add a `UILabel` to the cell setting it's tag to 300. Then after the if statement we will have either a brand new cell or a reused cell with text already in the label. No matter either way we simply change the text of the existing label to whatever it should be considering the row. In this way we avoid creating views over and over.

If you are dead-set on caching your `UITableViewCells` you could do so like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row < _cells.count){
        return [_cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // _cells is an NSMutableArray setup in viewDidLoad
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@""];
    cell.textLabel.text = [source objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // source is an NSArray of NSStrings I set up in viewDidLoad
    [_cells addObject:cell];
    return cell;
}
```

**Note** When running this on device don't be surprised when in the console you see `Received memory warning` What's efficient & what's easy are often not the same.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Modified it a bit and it's kinda working. But do you have any idea on how to increase loading time because I add quite a few subviews, and I thought if I saved it it would save it's subviews and reload. Thoughts?

Comment: Added a NSLog in my cell == nil and it only came up 8 times. even when i scrolled down, it's repeating them.

Comment: The dequeue process speeds up tableview scrolling. You said you had about 8 cells that repeated over and over. That's good because those tableviewcells are only being created once. The the tableview's dequeue method gives you a tableviewcell that has scrolled off screen so that you can change it's content and redisplay it, instead of creating a new tableviewcell.

Comment: Problem is that my objects change in size. therefore this wouldn't compeltely work.

Comment: I have two kinds of cells, and I a making a sms-like app. Where the speech bubbles fit the text and the person's profile picture changes. would changing all that content be better instead of creating and adding it to the subview?

Comment: If you are using two distinctly differently laid-outs then you should consider using two different `reuseIdentifier:`s. There is no official rule preventing you from caching cells in an `NSMutableArray` by their rows, and displaying the cached rows in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up now, `cell.selectionStyle`, `cell.backgroundColor`, and `cell.contentView.backgrounColor`, etc., only get set when `if (cell == nil)` is true. You need to move that code outside the if statement block, so that it gets called both when `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` produces a cell and when it has no cells in inventory and produces nothing (i.e., nil).